# track php curl_exec traffic

Tags: php, curl

I am looking for a way to track the curl execution in PHP. Now what I have is a regular curl call like this..

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'name1:value1',
  'name2:value2',
  'name3:value3',
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
...other params and data...
```

then run execution

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now I `$result` returns me NULL, i would like to see the log of whole execution for debug. Can any of you kindly tell me how to debug the `curl_exec`?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` option:

```
curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
     $result1 = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
   $result2 = (curl_getinfo($ch));
   print_r($result1);
    print_r($result2);
```